# Actions in Humble: Cancel action in action client

Tags: ros2, callback, action, rclpy

for learning purposes I'm trying to play around with the tutorial (rclpy) for writing an action server + client.

So, my action server is providing me with a fibonacci sequence up to n items and publishes feedback after each iteration.

In the client node I want to use the feedback_callback function to cancel/ abort the goal.
I've found action_client's method _cancel_goal but this should not be used in callbacks b/c of deadlocks.

Then there is '_cancel_goal_async' which returns a future, but it never stops the execution of the action server.

What is the correct way to react to feedback and cancel the current goal execution based on that? Thanks!

My client:

```
import rclpy
from rclpy.action import ActionClient
from rclpy.node import Node
from rcl_interfaces.msg import ParameterDescriptor

from fibonacci_interface.action import Fibonacci

class FibonacciActionClient(Node):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('fibonacci_action_client')
        self._action_client = ActionClient(self, Fibonacci, 'fibonacci')
        self.param_order = self.declare_parameter('order', 3, ParameterDescriptor(description="Order of fibonacci sequence")).value
        self.get_logger().info(f"Initialized param order:={self.param_order}")
        
        while not self._action_client.server_is_ready():
            self._action_client.wait_for_server(timeout_sec=1)
        self.get_logger().info("Found action server!")
        

    def send_goal(self):
        goal_msg = Fibonacci.Goal()
        goal_msg.order = self.param_order
        async_request = self._action_client.send_goal_async(goal_msg, self.feedback_callback)
        async_request.add_done_callback(self.goal_response_callback)
        return async_request


    def goal_response_callback(self, future):
        """Callback gets called when the action server responded to our goal: Accept or Reject"""
        self.goal_handle = future.result()
        
        # If the server didn't accepted the goal the node is destroyed
        if not self.goal_handle.accepted:
            self.get_logger().info('Goal rejected :(')
            rclpy.shutdown()
            return

        self.get_logger().info('Goal accepted :)')

        result_future = self.goal_handle.get_result_async()
        result_future.add_done_callback(self.get_result_callback)

    
    def feedback_callback(self, feedback_msg):
        partial_sequence = list(feedback_msg.feedback.partial_sequence)
        self.get_logger().info(f'Received feedback: {partial_sequence}')
        
        if partial_sequence[-1] > 5:
            self.get_logger().warning(f"Cancel goal, last sequence's item is greater than 5!")
            self._action_client._cancel_goal(self.goal_handle)


    def get_result_callback(self, future):
        result = future.result().result
        sequence = list(result.sequence)
        self.get_logger().info(f'Result: {sequence}')
        rclpy.shutdown()



def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)
    action_client = FibonacciActionClient()
    action_client.send_goal()
    rclpy.spin(action_client)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And the server looks like this:

```
import rclpy
from rclpy.action import ActionServer, GoalResponse
from rclpy.node import Node
import time

from fibonacci_interface.action import Fibonacci


class FibonacciActionServer(Node):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('fibonacci_action_server')
        self._action_server = ActionServer(self,Fibonacci,'fibonacci', 
                                           execute_callback=self.execute_callback, 
                                           goal_callback=self.goal_callback)


    def goal_callback(self, goal):
        order = goal.order
        if order <= 1:
            self.get_logger().info(f"REJECT goal: {order=}")
            return GoalResponse.REJECT
        self.get_logger().info(f"ACCEPT goal: {order=}")
        return GoalResponse.ACCEPT


    def execute_callback(self, goal_handle):
        """"Callback method for receiving goals. Must return a result message for the action type."""
        order = goal_handle.request.order
        result = Fibonacci.Result()
        feedback = Fibonacci.Feedback()
        self.get_logger().info(f'Start executing goal... | {order=}')

        goal_handle.succeed()

        sequence = [0, 1]
        for i in range(1, order - 1):
            time.sleep(1)
            sequence = sequence + [sequence[i-1] + sequence[i]]
            self.get_logger().info(f"Feedback: Partial sequence has a length of {len(sequence)}")
            feedback.partial_sequence = sequence
            goal_handle.publish_feedback(feedback)

        result.sequence = sequence
        self.get_logger().info(f"Result: Sequence has a length of {len(sequence)}")
        return result


def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)
    server = FibonacciActionServer()
    server.get_logger().info("Starting action server ...")
    rclpy.spin(server)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The action definition is in a separate package:

```
int32 order #request
---
int32[] sequence # result
---
int32[] partial_sequence #feedback
```

Comment: I was trying out your code, and found out that you have a custom interface which would not enable others to run your code. When posting on forums, please keep in mind to include a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This will enable others to try out what you have done, and make changes from there. :)

Comment: Well, you're right, it has. I appended it to the initial post.

Answer (score 0):

you'll want to use the cancel_goal_async method on the *goal handle* not the action client itself.

You can retrieve the goal handle in the callback when the action accepts the goal.

Here's a full example: https://github.com/ros2/examples/blob/master/rclpy/actions/minimal_action_client/examples_rclpy_minimal_action_client/client_cancel.py

Hope that helps!

([permalink to the example as of 23 Oct 2023](https://github.com/ros2/examples/blob/1d97c4fc7445554f6f85f63305d424fc017212a0/rclpy/actions/minimal_action_client/examples_rclpy_minimal_action_client/client_cancel.py))